# Javascript loading issue in Magento

Tags: javascript, cms-pages

I am loading an external script on a Magento CMS page. On the CMS page, I have the following div:

```
<div id="feefo-service-review-widgetId" class="feefo-review-widget-service">
  </div>
```

And in the footer I put the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://api.feefo.com/api/javascript/marsden"></script>
```

The page that should load the info is the following:

http://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/feefo-2

The problem is that initially not all reviews are loaded. I noticed that if I click on a link and go back, then all reviews are loaded. Is it a problem with the loading of the script? Is there a workaround? I also tried to add 'asycn' but no success :( Any pointer much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site in console error. the problem is third party API ("https://api.feefo.com/api/javascript/marsden). So you can allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your .htaccess or your php.

For more reference :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743396/cors-cannot-use-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin-when-credentials-flag-i?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I added the following to my .htaccess file but still not luck :(                                                               
# Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
# End